# Android thermal printer not accepting alignment bytes

Tags: android, bluetooth, thermal-printer

I'm using Analogics Thermal printer to print bill receipt from android device. They provided sdk for the printer but there is no any info about the text alignment i.e Center Align, Right Align, by default Left Align is working.

So far i have tried below command to print:

```
private static final byte[] ALIGN_LEFT = {0x1B, 0x61, 0};
private static final byte[] ALIGN_CENTER = {0x1B, 0x61, 1};
private static final byte[] ALIGN_RIGHT = {0x1B, 0x61, 2};
```

or

```
public static final byte[] ALIGN_LEFT = new byte[]{27, 97, 0};
public static final byte[] ALIGN_CENTER = new byte[]{27, 97, 1};
public static final byte[] ALIGN_RIGHT = new byte[]{27, 97, 2};
```

My print command is below:

```
public boolean printData(byte[] msg) {
    boolean flag = false;
    try {
        this.mmOutputStream.write(msg);
        flag = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return flag;
}

public boolean printData(String msg) {
    boolean flag = false;
    try {
        this.mmOutputStream.write(msg.getBytes());
        this.mmOutputStream.flush();
        flag = true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return flag;
}
```

I wanted to print command like product name should be left, quantity + price to be right aligned.

```
public static String nameLeftValueRight(String leftValue, String rightValue) {
    return applyParametersToPrinter(leftValue, DataConstants.ALIGN_LEFT) +
            applyParametersToPrinter(rightValue, DataConstants.ALIGN_RIGHT);
}
 public static String applyParametersToPrinter(String data, byte[] param) {
    String s = new String(param);
    return String.valueOf(s) + data;
}
```

Comment: Chiru, did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: @NinjoeQuah Nope

Answer (score 3):

Use Below Command for set alignment in thermal printer.

```
public static final byte[] PRINT_ALIGN_LEFT = new byte[] { 0x1b, 'a', 0x00 };
public static final byte[] PRINT_ALIGN_RIGHT = new byte[] { 0x1b, 'a', 0x02 };
public static final byte[] PRINT_ALIGN_CENTER = new byte[] { 0x1b, 'a', 0x01 };
```

Comment: 'a' is 0x61 in hex value, check: https://bluesock.org/~willg/dev/ascii

Answer (score 0):

This is a document with commands of Epson - compatible receipt printers: http://www.aures-support.fr/DE/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/ESCPOS-command-manual20160428.pdf.

It says about `1B 61`:

> The command is enabled only when processed at the beginning of the  line in standard mode.

Additionally, I am not completely sure if conversion of bytes to a string and back really results in the original bytes. This is something that you can check by writing the bytes that are sent to printer to log.

An alternative approach for alignment is to insert spaces. It works as long as the characters have fixed width and you know the number of characters in a line. This is not a great solution, but could be the only way for aligning something on the left and something on the right in the same line. I know an application that does it exactly this way.

Comment: I have tried the same, 1B 61 also, but no use. I'm planning on the same with manual alignment. Thank you.

Comment: The printer could be not Epson-compatible.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final byte[] ALIGN_LEFT = {0x1B, 0x61, 0};
private static final byte[] ALIGN_CENTER = {0x1B, 0x61, 1};
public static final byte[] ALIGN_RIGHT = new byte[]{27, 97, 2};
```

I tested these commands on my printer.
I think the printer you are using is not compatible for these commands.

Answer (score 0):

Print above bytes for specific alignment then print that bytes which you want to align:

```
byte[] PRINT_ALIGN_LEFT = new byte[] { 0x1b, 'a', 0x00 };
byte[] PRINT_ALIGN_RIGHT = new byte[] { 0x1b, 'a', 0x02 }; 
byte[] PRINT_ALIGN_CENTER = new byte[] { 0x1b, 'a', 0x01 };
```

Comment: print above bytes for specific alignment then print that bytes which you want to align

Answer (score 0):

There are different commands for different printers, you should check the printer command manual.

If your printer is from **starmicronics** then

```
//Decimal
byte[] AlignLeft = {27, 29, 97,48};
byte[] AlignCenter = {27, 29, 97,49};
byte[] AlignRight = {27, 29, 97,50};

//HEX
byte[] AlignLeft = {0x1B, 0x1D, 0x61,0x00};
byte[] AlignCenter = {0x1B, 0x1D, 0x61,0x01};
byte[] AlignRight = {0x1B, 0x1D, 0x61,0x02};
```

If you are using **epson** printer

```
//Decimal
byte[] AlignLeft = {27, 97,48};
byte[] AlignCenter = {27, 97,49};
byte[] AlignRight = {27, 97,50};

//HEX
byte[] AlignLeft = {0x1B, 0x61,0x00};
byte[] AlignCenter = {0x1B, 0x61,0x01};
byte[] AlignRight = {0x1B, 0x61,0x02};
```